# NextJS SSG with dynamic route from Firebase

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am struggling to find a way, if it is even possible, to have a dynamic route where new routes are also working when there is a new post added to Firestore. Is this possible?

The problem I have now is that dynamic routes are working, but when I add a new document to Firestore the route of that document is just throwing a 404.

Any help would be much appreciated.